# Retrieve Large Data From MySQL DB With Chunks And Save Them Dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, large-data

I want to retrieve about 100 million rows and 30 columns of data from an SQL database into a dataframe where I can sort and filter based on certain requirements. I only have 2 Gig memory. Everything comes to a standstill even though I am using chunksize. Here is my code.

````
import pymysql
chunksize = 100
import pandas as pd
import pymysql.cursors
from urllib import parse```

sqlEngine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://username:%s@localhost/db' % parse.unquote_plus('password'))
dbConnection    = sqlEngine.connect()

for chunk in pd.read_sql("select * from db.db_table", dbConnection, chunksize = chunksize):
    print(chunk)

Do somrthing with chunk(chunk is the dataframe that has all the 100 million columns )
````

I have reduced my chunksize but still not getting anything.

Comment: With a query like `select * from db.db_table`, the database still has to start retrieving all 30 million rows. Choose an indexed column you can order by, order by it and add suitable `LIMIT ... OFFSET ...` to begin with

Comment: I need the entire data for data analysis.

Comment: What analysis? You can probably do a lot of it in SQL instead of trying to load things into Pandas.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment, something like this.

I foresee you're going to have a bad time trying to fit 100 million rows x 30 columns in 2 gigabytes of memory, though.

```
df = None
for offset in itertools.count(step=chunksize):
    print("Reading chunk %d..." % offset)
    query = "select * from db.db_table order by id limit %d offset %d" % (chunksize, offset)
    chunk_df = pd.read_sql(query, dbConnection)
    if not chunk_df:  # TODO: this check might not be correct
        # No data in new chunk, so we probably have it all
        break
    if not df:
        df = chunk_df
    else:
        df = pd.concat([df, chunk_df], copy=False)

# do things with DF
```

Comment: that is still the issue, but will find a work around it, thank you for the help?